# Cannot open .oft, file already opened or no permission

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, outlook, blob

Case:

I have a .oft file I'm serving trough an api. When opening the .oft file locally, I can open it (even multiple times simultaneously).

BUT when I run my Angular front-end, Spring-Boot back-end locally and I download the file, I cannot open it and see this error message:

```
We can't open 'C:\Users\(username)\Downloads\trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate.oft'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.        

To check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.
```

- I have tried closing outlook, reopening it and trying to open this file but same error remains.
- I have opened the file in notepad both before and after download and it holds almost the same characters, except special character types like ÿ are replaced by question marks in black diamond shapes.
- I have checked the permissions of the file before and after download, they are exactly the same.
- I have copied the file before downloading to the Downloads folder to try and replicate this, but there was no issue so it only happens with the file after download.

Based on this, I'm thinking it might have to do with loss of those special characters, how can I fix this please?

Here is my code:

Spring-Boot controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate", produces = "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = getClass()
          .getResourceAsStream("/eml/trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate.oft");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

Angular service:

```
public downloadTrnMail(): Observable<Blob>{

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Accept', "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8");

    const httpGetOptions =
      {
          headers: headers,
          responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
      };
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(`${UtilsService.baseUrl}/refreshPlanning/trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate`, httpGetOptions);
  }
```

Angular component that subscribes:

```
emailRefreshPlanning(){

    this.refreshPlanningService.downloadTrnMail().subscribe(response => {

        const blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8"});
        fileSaver.saveAs(blob, "trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate.oft");
      });
  }
```

The fileSaver variable is from the ngx-filesaver library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver

Comment: How are you running the Spring Boot application? If you are running it from command line, try running the CMD as Administrator.

Comment: Why do you need to download the .oft file somewhere? Isn't better to use Graph API or EWS?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev customer want's to open a formatted mail from the browser, since that is not possible we propose to downoad the email as a workaround. .oft is a microsoft template type that should be safe to download (.eml gives warning it could harm computer)